# jquery dropdownbox auto populated with mysql data

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I've got 2 dropdownboxes. Dropdownbox 1 shows all the tables from a database. When dropdownbox 1 is selected; dropdownbox 2 will be populated with tablefields from the selected table.

dropdownbox 1:
This dropdown is populated with the following mysql query: "show tables from testdb"

dropdownbox 2:
This dropdown will auto populate when dropdownbox 1 is selected. Dropdownbox 2 will be populate with the following query: "describe tablename" //tablename selected from dropdownbox 1

I want to make this using jquery. Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

There's a good writeup on it here:

http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

You are looking for related dropdowns, and this does exactly what you  need, as long as you can provide it with the table names and columns.

I should be able to help you further, if you give me more information about what sort of backend technology you are using.

Cheers

Comment: I'd throw the word cascade in there too, will help in searching for more info.

Comment: Your example is using submit to populate dropdownbox 2. I need another method.